# Mysql query with max prices

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySql. I have two tables. One for products and other to prices.
I need list all products with your latest prices.

Products:

```
id name  cat
1  prod1  a
2  prod2  b
3  prod3  c
```

Prices:

```
id prod_id cod   price  
1  1       cod1  10.00 
2  3       cod2  20.00
3  1       cod3  5.00
4  3       cod4  12.00
```

I´d like a result with all products and the corresponding price and cod considering the max id with list prices.

For example:

I need a result as:

```
id name   cat  cod     price
1  prod1  a    cod3    5.00
2  prod2  b    null    null
3  prod3  c    cod4    12.00
```

I have tried something as below, but I don´t think to be a good solution:

```
select  A.id,A.name, B.cat,B.cod,B.price      
      from products A
      left join prices B ON B.prod_id = A.id 
          AND B.id = 
            (
              SELECT MAX(B.id) 
              FROM prices Z 
              WHERE Z.prod_id = A.id
            )
```

Comment: Wouldn't the max price for prod_id 1 be `10.00`? What is the logic here to get `5.00`? Is it that you want the price for a product based on the max of the `prices.id` for that product?

Comment: @JNevill `the max id` so basically the last one entered for any product

Comment: @JNevill Hi, the latest id entered in the table prices contains the price I want(my current price to each product)

Comment: "I don´t think to be a good solution:"  Why not? What's not good about it?

Comment: @Andy Lester Because I am not sure if the subquery with max() is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use row_number to get the max price on Prices table and then join with the product table:

```
with cte as (
           select *,
                  row_number() over(partition by prod_id order by price  desc) row_num
           from Prices        
 )  select pd.id,pd.name,pd.cat,cte.cod,cte.price
    from Products pd
    inner join cte on cte.prod_id =pd.id
    where cte.row_num=1;
```

Above query returns the max price which is not the expected result on the question.If you want to take the max id change `order by price  desc` to `order by id desc`

Comment: Thank you so much. It solves my problem